# UNIX whois command via PHP and system()

Tags: php, forms, unix, system, whois

I wanna get a easy form by using php and unix system command 'whois'. Where is the error? :-/

```
        <form action="whois.php" method="get" >
<p>
    Domainadresse (ohne <i>http://</i> oder <i>www</i>) <input type="text" name="domainname" value="teleschirm.info" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Okay, Abfrage starten!" />
</p>
</form>
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$last_line = system('whois 
    echo $_POST[domainname]
' , $retval);
echo '</pre>'
?>
```

Comment: does your code returns any error ?

Comment: lovely shell injection attack vulnerability. literally enjoy having your server entirely destroyed. e.g. `$_POST['domainname'] = '; rm -rf ');`

Comment: @MarcB I made a similar point, and someone downvoted that thought :-)

Comment: @KevinSeifert: indeed. people keep saying php's insecure...they really should be saying most(some? few?) php developers couldn't care less about security.

Comment: Your language has libraries to deal with doing whois query so why escaping to the shell? This is both a security and performance nightmare...

Answer (score 0):

form uses method get, but the php code uses a post variable. pick one for both.

the use of the variable in system is wrong:

```
$last_line = system('whois '.$_POST['domainname'] , $retval);
```

you do noting with the returned value:

`echo $retval;`

as noted by others: user input needs to be sanitized with either  `escapeshellarg()` or `escapeshellcmd()`

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes. What's between single quotes is not evaluated, so your variable isn't copied into the string you pass in `system`. Change the line to

```
system("whois {$_POST['domainname']}" , $retval);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth pointing out, that there's a major security hole here and this should generally be avoided.  User input should not be passed to `system()` without carefully sanitizing it. What happens if somebody's domain is this?

```
sorry.com; rm -rf /
```

It will delete everything on the server. You'll want to sanitize the data, possibly with `escapeshellarg()` and/or `escapeshellcmd()`.

I'd delete anything outside of `[a-z0-9]` and possibly a couple non-harmful special chars like `_`, `-`, `.`  Single quote the argument.

:-)

Comment: This should be the only sane reply to the question. The error clearly starts with using system() to do a whois query.